# Записать выборку из mysql в массив php

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, как можно вывести значение из базы данных в массив.
У меня имеется база данных с двумя столбцами. `id` - id отдела и `name` - наименование.
Я делаю выборку

```
$todb = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM otd');
$mass = array();

while($rws = mysqli_fetch_assoc($todb)){
   $mass[] = $rws['id'];
   $mass[] = $rws['otdel_name'];
}
print_r( $mass );
```

в данном коде в массив mass записываются в каждую строку свой параметр.

```
 [0] => 1
 [1] => Руководство
 [2] => 2 
 [3] => Бухгалтерия
```

Я же хочу чтоб массив записался вот таким форматом

```
 [1] => Руководство
 [2] => Бухгалтерия
```

Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: `$mass[$rws['id']] = $rws['name']`

Comment: Спасибо большое! это подошло!